# Issue when check on file creation date in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a file and I need to replace this file with new file based on its creation date, so if the creation date of this file is before 06/23/2013 for example, then I will delete it and add new file so the new creation date will be 06/23/2013, but if the creation date is after or equal 06/23/2013 then do nothing.

When apply above logic on dev environment everything went ok without problems, but when I deploy it to production (iTunes) the condition = true that means the code always enter to condition before 06/23/2013 and delete the file and create a new file.

My code is:

```
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath]) {
NSDate *creationDate = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:writableDBPath error:&error] objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];

BOOL result = NO;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *issueDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-05-22"];

NSDateComponents *creationDateComponents = [CURRENT_CALENDAR components:DATE_COMPONENTS fromDate:creationDate];
NSDateComponents *issueDateComponents = [CURRENT_CALENDAR components:DATE_COMPONENTS fromDate:issueDate];

NSTimeInterval secondsBetweenCreationIssue = [[CURRENT_CALENDAR dateFromComponents:creationDateComponents] timeIntervalSinceDate:[CURRENT_CALENDAR dateFromComponents:issueDateComponents]];

if ((lround((secondsBetweenCreationIssue/86400))) <= 0) {
    result = YES;
}
else{
    result = NO;
}
//if the file is OLD
if (result) {
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
}
```

Comment: When you say dev / production, do you mean simulator / device? Are you taking locale into consideration anywhere?

Comment: no it's development/ production or development version and store version

Comment: it's working well on device and simulator in the development phase but the version from the store doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

First thing, you should not use `NSDateFormatter` like that. `NSDateFormatter` is expensive to create, and expensive to use. Since you know your date perfectly I recommend you use `NSDateComponents` to create the `issueDate`:

```
NSDateComponents *issueDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
issueDateComponents.day = 23;
issueDateComponents.month = 6;
issueDateComponents.year = 2013;
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdenfier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *issueDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:issueDateComponents];
```

(Notice that I use the gregorian calendar, because your date seems to be from that calendar. The user current calendar could be another one, and that date will not work).

Second thing. Instead of hard-coding the number of seconds in a day, you should extract the date components, and use them to compare:

```
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath]) {
  NSDate *creationDate = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:writableDBPath error:&error] objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];

  // Here should be the code from the previous example

  // Again, use a gregorian calendar, not the user current calendar, which
  // could be whatever. I'm not sure every calendar has the same days and
  // months, so we better be sure.
  NSDateComponents *creationDateComponents = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:creationDate];
  creationDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:creationDateComponents];

  if ([creationDate compare:issueDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
  }
}
```

(You should check if time zones affect this calculation in any way, I’m not sure).

I think the problem you are seeing with your code is the use of the user current calendar (and locale), which can affect the way the `NSDateFormatter` parse the date, and your complicated calculation of the time interval.

Another thing that bugs me is that it looks like your flag will only be set to `YES` if the `secondsBetweenCreationIssue` is only less than 1 day away, but dates oldest than that will not pass the test.

Hope it helps.